# Stripped Threads on inside of Oil Drain (Motorcycle; '72 Honda CB750)

Tags: honda, motorcycle, oil, oil-leak, cb750

I recently bought a '72 Honda CB750. There is a small oil leak (just a consistent but seldom drip) from the oil drain plug underneath the bike.

The other day I went to change the oil for the first time and found that the plug seemed to be stripped because I kept turning it and it wouldn't come out. I was able to turn and shake it enough to get it out and when it came out, in the threads of the plug, were metal shavings. When I cleaned it off, the drain plug seemed totally fine. I'm gathering that the thread shavings came from the drain itself and when I reapplied the plug, the leak persisted.

Any ideas on how best to fix this. I'm a novice when it comes to motorcycles and mechanics but I'm here to learn.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repair kits are available to fix stripped plugs. [INSTRUCTIONS FOR REPAIR KIT LISTED BELOW](http://www.timesert.com/html/oilpan.pdf)
The CB750 should be a 14 x 1.5 x 13mm plug size.
[LINK TO REPAIR KIT](http://www.timesert.com/html/drainplug.html)

The basic concept of steps to repair involve:
1, Cleaning and removing old threads.  This is usually done with a drill or ream.
2. The hole is resized and tapped to fit an hardened insert into it, if the kit uses that approach.  Some kits just do a new tap size for an enlarged size oil plug. (I do not prefer the enlarged size plug that some kits use).
3. The insert (if used) is screwed into the prepared hole until it is fully seated and locks into place.
4. Oil drain is now ready for plug and use.

These are only generalized steps you must follow the specific directions that are for the kit type you select.

Comment: While links are encouraged, you should put the general steps into the body of this post. It helps if the page you've linked to goes away or changes its URL for some reason. It keeps the information here within the site.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I will see if I can find or generate a generalized set of steps as the steps listed fit the specific kit listed.  If that kit is not available then those steps may not be the same or done in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

@spicetraders answer is more accurate in regards to doing the 'right' fix but I did also come across another option for those that are looking for a quick fix.

The Dorman Oil-Tite is basically a rubber oil drain plug that expands to fill the hole and stop the leak.

There is a quick video on YouTube of a guy who's used them on his Hondas:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdAvBAJaBwQ

Again, not necessarily the 'right' way to do it but it seems to get the job done in a slightly cheaper way and is a little quicker.